# I can't change java memory for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, debian

Note: My OS *Debian 7*, *Java 8*, 2Gb *RAM*

Here is what I did:

1. I went this way: `/etc/default/`
2. Then: `vim jenkins`
3. Then edit: `JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx1048m"`

   [image]
4. I exit from editor with saving: `:wq`
5. Now I make do: `service jenkins restart`
6. Now I go to my *Jenkins* and watching monitoring with plugin *JavaMelody*.
7. So, I see that no changes have occurred.

   [image]

   I ask for help in this case, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved and I did the following:

1. I went this way: `/etc/default/`
2. Then: `vim jenkins`
3. I'm add in jenkins `JAVA=/usr/bin/java`
   and `JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1024m"`

   [image]
4. I exit from editor with saving: `:wq`
5. Then after I made: `service jenkins restart`
6. Now I go to my Jenkins and watching monitoring with plugin *JavaMelody*.

   [image]
7. So, I see that this works for me.

   I'm hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

From the [official guide](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/209715698-How-to-add-Java-arguments-to-Jenkins-), if you're using RedHat Linux based distributions, you should use `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS`.

```
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx1048m"
```

Note: For me, the file location was `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` and it only had `JENKINS_ARGS=""`. Assigning `Xmx` value to it did not work. You should leave that entry as is and instead, add the `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS` entry in the file just like i specified above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestion, but for me that not works.

Comment: I have Debian 9 and by default it had `JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"`. I just appended `Xmx` to it: `JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1024m"` and then restarted Jenkins (`sudo service jenkins restart`). I can see the new `Xmx` settings.

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh: Glad to hear that you were able to solve the issue. :) I suggest you should post your solution and accept _that post_ as an answer instead of marking my post as an answer. It will help others know what _actually_ worked for you. :)